# Метод антиотладки или баг Olly`ки ?

Tags: отладка, ассемблер, исследование

**Доброго времени суток!**

При исследовании одной софтины мне встретился такой вот фрагмент кода, после которого исследуемое приложение ломается с ошибкой об обращении к недоступной области памяти( *Access Violation* ):

[image]

[Хорошее качество изображения.](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130802/JKBWGRH8.png)

Здесь можно видеть то, что обычно мы привыкли наблюдать в секции данных. Но это, что очевидно, секция кода.
Мне очень хотелось бы, чтобы вы просветили: что это? Метод антиотладки? Неправильная интерпретация кода в OllyDBG? Или же JIT код?

**Спасибо.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это неподдерживаемые OllyDbg инструкции. Вручную вбил неправильно распознанные байты в шестнадцатеричный редактор, сохранил в файл и открыл в [HT Editor](http://hte.sourceforge.net/) в режиме дизассемблирования, получилось следующее:

```
660fd6442430                   movq        [esp+00000030], xmm0
660fd6442438                   movq        [esp+00000038], xmm0
```

Видим, что "Олька" не только не распознала 5 байт, помеченных как данные, но и неверно распознала последующие 7 байт (т.е. все вплоть до `AND AL,38` включительно).

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Интересно вот только, почему в Olly не соизволили "вшить" распознавание жалких 57 инструкций MMX/SSE. Все современные процессоры Intel поддерживают технологию SIMD SSE, а в самом популярном отладчике поддержки нет...

Comment: @0xFFh, на www.ollydbg.de декларируется поддержка MMX/SSE, хотя возможно версия 1.10 (если вы пользуетесь ею) как раз таки их не поддерживает.